# How to create a object with prop as function and attribute

Tags: javascript

I need to create a fake object that accepts the following calls:

```
object.loading()
object.loading.close()
```

I've tried to create something like:

```
obj = {
  loading: function() {
     close: function() {
     }
   }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: In your object can not includes 2 properties have a same name

Answer (score 2):

This is one approach:

```js
const object = {};
object.loading = function() {console.log('loading')};
object.loading.close = function() {console.log('closing')};

object.loading();
object.loading.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something to be both a function *and* have its own methods, you need to create the function and then assign the methods to it afterward. What you tried above is to put `close` in the *body* of the function, and that won't work.

Try this:

```js
var obj = {
  loading: function () {
  }
};
obj.loading.close = function () {};

obj.loading();       // no error
obj.loading.close(); // no error
```

Comment: but I cant call `obj.loading()` too

Comment: @AjjjHsh Sorry. Somehow I missed that. Please see my updated example.